# Is the RSSI field of the CLBeacon class safe to use wrt the submission process?

Tags: ios, clbeacon

I was wondering if anybody could confirm that the RSSI field of the CLBeacon class is safe to use in an iOS app wrt the app submission process? I was told today that the usage of the RSSI field of the CLBeacon class will make the app rejected. However, I could not find anything int he Apple doc saying so. Any confirmation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

JB

Answer (score 0):

[The `rssi` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeacon_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLBeacon/rssi) is publicly exposed. The act of using this property will not cause your app to be rejected by the Apple review process.